# Is git show <tag> supposed to give me a full patch? How can I turn that off?

Tags: git

I've been doing some work with annotated tags in git trying to improve our release management. One thing I've found is that anytime I run `git show <tag>` it not only gives me the tag, note, and commit message but also the patch information for that commit. Generally I'm only wanting to view the tag and commit info, not the patch.

Here's an example of what I see:

```
$ git show 9.2
tag 9.2
Tagger: Me <me@email.com>

My tag message

commit d65f1a8d98af24e5989ebd685069fbac63681080
Author: Me <me@email.com>

    Some commit message

diff --git a/path/to/file.php b/path/to/file.php
index 5030b1b..a5a428e 100644
--- a/path/to/file.php
+++ b/path/to/file.php
@@ -274,9 +274,12 @@ abstract class ClassName extends BaseClass
             $obj->setSomething(NULL);

             $obj->save();
-
-            $myDao = new DetailsDao();
-                       # Create a new Detail record
+
+                       $myDao = \DetailsDao::getById($id);
+
+                       if (!isset($myDao )) {
+                               $myDao = new myDao ();
+                       }

             $myDao ->setExternalKey($extId);
             $myDao ->setSource($memberEmail);
```

I'm not sure why I'm seeing everything from the `diff` line onwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected output.

It looks like you are looking for the `--summary` option which will generate condensed summary of extended header information:

```
git show --summary 9.2
```

You may also like `--shortstat`, which will give you output like this at the end rather than a full diff:

```
3 files changed, 27 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```